# How can I get the username of the person who triggered a build in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

I am trying to integrate Atlassian Bamboo with a CloudFormation template that creates and deploys environments in AWS.  One of the tags we add to the VPCs and EC2 instances is the name of the engineer that triggered the build.

I can't find a bamboo variable that contains the name of the user that triggered a build.  I found one that has the username of the person who created a release in Jira, but this isn't what I want.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+variables

Is there a way to get this variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName`, that will be the name of the person who manually triggered a build but if it was off a trigger this will not be present.

For the name of the person who didn't trigger the build manually but did it through a source code commit then you could probably be:

```
git log <commitFrom>..<commitTo> --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse
```

And then you could use `repository.revision.number` for the current revision and then `repository.previous.revision.number` for the previous revision.

Comment: If you want to get the commiter email in a variable in your script, you can do :

    COMMITER="$(git log ${bamboo.repository.previous.revision.number}..${bamboo.repository.revision.number} --format=%aE --reverse)"

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq tried the command you specified but getting an empty value. [Bamboo version used is 7.1.4]. Any suggestions?

Comment: @saravana Sorry for being late to come back to you, you probably have a different git version or a different shell. Also you can try to debug the values of ${bamboo.repository.previous.revision.number} and ${bamboo.repository.revision.number} in your script to check if these variables exist. The purpose is to build a valid `git log` command that finds the email of the user who commited last.